# Built in column shortcode on Wordpress - nice border solution

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout

I'm hoping to find a nice way to edit the css on this page:

http://carbonbi.com/build/?page_id=46

I'm using the wordpress layout shortcodes to create three separate columns. I'd like to add a border in between the first and the second column and the second and the third.

I realize using the built in shortcode might not be the best way to do this, and may require creating my own class to handle this, but if anyone has any effective ways to work on this it would be nice to see.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No borders on this page when I view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a general tip: by using plugins like "Web Developer" for Firefox (my favorite) or simply left clicking an element and choosing "inspect element"  (Firebug is a good choice, although most browsers have their own, firefox actually has a spacy 3d one that can come in handy) you can get the names of classes and id's used by plugins and the like, and then add them to your style.css and edit away!

Bonus Tip: Firebug let's you edit the CSS in real time to preview what it would look like without having to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS to your `stylesheet.css`:

```
body .three_col {
    margin-right: 2%;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding-right: 1.75%;
}
body .last {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

This will add a 1px solid gray border in-between the columns.